# Maven PMD plugin reporting not going to correct directory

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin, pmd

I have the following configuration settings under my pom.xml to generate reports for PMD code analysis:

```
<pluginManagement>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pmd</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>code-analysis/reports/html</outputDirectory>
                            <targetDirectory>code-analysis/reports/</targetDirectory>
                            <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                            <rulesets>
                                <ruleset>code-analysis/rulesets/pmd-custom-rules.xml</ruleset>
                            </rulesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

But after I run mvn pmd:pmd I didn't get the report in the outputDirectory I want. Does setting the aggregate=true only generates 1 report for all the sub-projects under maven? How do I configure it so that it will only generate 1 report to the output directory that I want?

Answer (score 0):

With Maven it is not possible to run a goal by execution(Id), that's only possible by calling it by phase. So if you want to run `pmd:pmd` from commandline AND have specific configuration, move the configuration outside the executions-block. Now it becomes general configuration. It'll be like:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.4</version>
   <configuration>
      ...
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```